# Change the_content() content inside a div in wordpress by post-ID with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to change the content inside a modal by post-id with ajax.

I have very limited knowledge about ajax and am still learning..

So I managed to load the ajax script but when I open the modal, I'm getting the content from all posts at once instead of every post on it's own.
What I'm trying to achive is a quick view for posts with ajax,
How can I use the rel attribute with the ID in order to change the_content() content inside the modal ?

In posts loop I have the button with dynamic post-id:

```
<a href="#" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary post-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
                QUICK VIEW
</a>
```

The modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div id="the-post-content" class="modal-content">


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In function.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_post_content', 'load_post_content' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post_content', 'load_post_content' );

function load_post_content() {

    $the_post_id = $_POST['the_ID'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'p' => $the_post_id
    );
    $ajax_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $the_content;

    if ( $ajax_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $ajax_query->have_posts() ) : $ajax_query->the_post();
    $the_content = the_content();
    endwhile;
    endif; 

    echo $the_content;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}

function enqueue_jquery_ajax(){
    ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".post-link").click(function(){
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    var ajaxurl = 'http://my-domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            'url': ajaxurl,
            'action': 'load_post_content',
            'the_ID': post_id
        },
        function(response){
            jQuery('#the-post-content').html(response);
        }
    );

    return false;
});
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_jquery_ajax', 99);
```

By the way. I know I should localize the script but for now I just want to make it work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: replace your load_post_content function with this function:

```
function load_post_content() {      
    $content_post = get_post($_POST['the_ID']);     
    $the_content = $content_post->post_content;     
    $the_content = apply_filters('the_content', $the_content);     
    $the_content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $the_content);      
    $title = get_the_title($content_post); // Title     
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($content_post); // Thumbnail   
    /* if you want display title and thubnails */
    $the_content = $title.$thumbnail.$the_content;

    print($the_content);      
    wp_reset_postdata();     
    die(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it's working . but now it gives me the related content in loop (same content, 3 times, as the number of the posts in page/loop). what do you think I should do?

Comment: update: I added to the query 'posts_per_page' => 1 and now It works great! don't know if this is a bad practice/

Comment: the function give you repetitive 3 time only in posts have child or all posts ??

Comment: what do you mean in post have child? In the category page, when I open the modal with the quick view I have created I get the same content printed 3 times in 3 separate <p> elements. Why 3? Because thats' the number of post in that category I guess

Comment: Do you remove while from your function ??

Comment: No..but I will try. sorry I'm still a noob 
but now I dont really know how to add the_title() and the_post_thumbnail() to this function

Comment: wow. thank you so much!
just need to replace "the_post_thumbnail" with "get_the_post_thumbnail" to make this answer perfect :]